# Setting up volume control vertical in video.js

Tags: volume, video.js

There i have been playing around with the HTML5 video.js video player component . And player is absolutely awesome and meet almost all my requirements .

The only issue i have ran into is it has a horizontal volume control bar and i want to place the volume control bar vertical similar to what it sets in flash fall back mode .

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Thanx

Comment: Do you have any attempts so far?

Comment: Realistically i didn't found and suitable information regarding it thats why i had to change my html5 player script and make further alteration by my own self . I chose mediaplayerjs as it provides more customization options than video js

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
vjs.ControlBar.prototype.options_ = {
  children: {
    'volumeMenuButton': {
      'volumeBar': {
        'vertical': true
      }
    }
  }
};
```