# how to make volume bar vertical in video.js player?

Tags: video.js

I have tried solution given here on the site but it didn't work.
[Setting up volume control vertical in video.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317159/setting-up-volume-control-vertical-in-video-js)
Where I can get best tutorial about video.js.. Any link?

Answer (score 15):

For version 6.2.0:

```
var options = {
    controlBar: {
        volumePanel: {inline: false}
    },
};

videojs('my-video', options);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The version I'm using is 6.2.5!

Answer (score 8):

Video.js 7.10.2

```
var player = videojs('my-video', {
  controlBar: {
    volumePanel: {
      inline: false
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Confirmed with 7.11.4

Comment: Works on v8.0.4 as well.

Comment: Works on 8.5.2 as well.

Answer (score 6):

For video.js 5.x:

```
var options = {
  controlBar: {
    volumeMenuButton: {
      inline: false,
      vertical: true
    }
  }
};

videojs('player', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const options: VideoJsPlayerOptions = {
        controlBar: {
          volumePanel: {
            inline: false,
            volumeControl: {
              vertical: true
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score -1):

This can be done. Please see:

http://jsbin.com/nidevo/2/edit?html,css,output

and

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/942

The howto you cite is for videojs 2.0

Comment: this doesn't work for me... volume bar disappers if I implement this.  btw I have videojs 5.0.2....

Comment: Sorry I thought it was 4.x. I'm pretty sure vertical rendering is broken ATM in 5.0: http://jsfiddle.net/w91vvjy0/4/ and https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2726